# PHP check values

Tags: php, foreach

We have 2 variables, `$id` and `$title`.

And a form field for a new `$title` variable:

```
foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $id_title = $title;
?>
    <input name="new_<?php echo $id; ?>_title" value="<?php echo $id_title; ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

How to check, is `$id_title` has been changed in the form, and do something if it is.

Like:

```
if ($id_title != $new_id_title) {
    make db query
}
```

There can be more than one input field on the page, different for each `$id`, we should check all of them.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the question? (You haven't actually asked a question here)

Comment: I think that you should put" <input name="new_<?php echo $id; ?>_title" value="<?php echo $id_title; ?>" />
<?php } ?>" inside foreach loop

Comment: I'm having a really hard time understanding this question.

Comment: @Ankur Mukherjee its already there, don't know how to check variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
foreach ($ids as $id) {
    if (isSet($_POST["new_{$id}_title"]) && $_POST["new_{$id}_title"] != $old_titles[$id]) {
        // Do foo
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean

```
foreach ($ids as $id) {
    $id_title = $title;
    if ($id_title != $_POST['new_'.$id.'_title']) {
       make db query
    }
}
```

?

Is the problem that you don't know how to get the `new_$id_title` field?

Btw. I don't see a point to assign `$title` to `$id_title`. It is the same for all anyway.